# Name of unshaved armpits

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

When people say "**pubic hair**" most will understand that they mean the unshaved bikini zone *(I'm, however, not sure whether this applies only to women)*. But what common expression is there for unshaved *(women)* armpits, if there is one at all?

I'm looking for a phrase or an idiom

Comment: Nope. If you want to sound scientific, you can say "axillary hair".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Pubic hair is gender neutral. Men and women may trim/shave/wax that area for hygienic, styling, and/or visual appeal
- Unshaved pits or Hairy armpits are likely referring to women's "naturally hairy armpits" since most men leave them or at most trim them.

There is currently an Instagram fad where women are showing their underarm hair.
It is called [Free your Pits](https://www.instagram.com/freeyourpits/?hl=en)

[image]

However excessive underarm hair may create comments regardless of gender.

[image: KOHEI UCIMURA]

Answer (score 2):

Is can be referred to as [**underarm hair**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underarm_hair), **armpit** is a bit colloquial.

A *common expression* might be

> **hairy pits**

**Pubic hair** can be used for both sexes, however

> **bush**

refers exclusively to the female gender.

Comment: **Underarm** is the modern name?

Comment: Not sure what you might mean by ***modern***, but it is another way of describing the hair under your arms. **Pit hair** might also be used since it is unambiguous.